# Removing Broken Image Box with JS not working correctly. Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I've created a method that automatically populates the view with the Carrierwave image that is being uploaded. But, the broken image box shows by default when I use it. I've added a JS function that removes the broken image box upon detection. The only problem is that the image doesn't repopulate the view after the method is called. I'll post the JS code below.

post.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(function () {
    function readURL(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
          $('#img_prev').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
    }


    //Add uploaded image to placeholder.
    $("#img-upload").change(function () {
      $('#img_prev').removeClass('hidden');
      readURL(this);

      //Remove Broken Image
      $('img').error(function () {
        $('img[src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '"]').remove();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` variable.

```
$('img').error(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: The broken image tag disappears when no image is present, but the function doesn't run the rest of the code when a photo is actually queued to be uploaded. (The image doesn't repopulate the view)